# Kernlab, user-defined kernel on chosen variables

Tags: r, kernel-trick

I want to make a user-defined kernel with different variables in the kernel and combine them. Does anyone know if this is possible with kernlab or what is wrong with my code?

I use these packages:

```
install.packages("caret")
library(caret)
install.packages("kernlab")
library(kernlab)
install.packages("mlbench")
library(mlbench)
data(BreastCancer)
```

Some data cleaning:

```
na_index <- which(is.na(BreastCancer[,7]))
BreastCancer <- BreastCancer[-na_index, ]
BreastCancer <- BreastCancer[,-1]
```

Say I write a Squared exponential kernel ( with lengthscale =1).

```
k_se_a <- function(x, y){
  res <- exp(-0.5*sum((x - y)^2))
  return(res)
}
class(k_se_a) <- "kernel"

model_0 <- gausspr(Class ~ Cell.size, data = BreastCancer, kernel = k_se_a)
pre_gp <- predict(model_0, BreastCancer[,-10])
conf_0 <- confusionMatrix(pre_gp, BreastCancer$Class, positive = "malignant")
conf_0$byClass[1]
# Sensitivity 
# 0.9497908
```

Here I have trained the model with only one variable, Cell.size, the second variable in the data set.

Now I try to get the same result, sensitivity = 0.9498, but by changing the user-defined kernel instead of explicitly writing it in the `gausspr()` function.

```
k_se_b <- function(x, y){
  res <- exp(-0.5*sum((x[c(2,10)] - y[c(2,10)])^2))
  return(res)
}
class(k_se_b) <- "kernel"

model_1 <- gausspr(Class ~ ., data = BreastCancer, kernel = k_se_b)
pre_gp <- predict(model_1, BreastCancer[,-10])
conf_1 <- confusionMatrix(pre_gp, BreastCancer$Class, positive = "malignant")
conf_1$byClass[1]
# Sensitivity 
# 0.2887029
```

The result is 0.2887 and not 0.9498 which I wanted. The motivation for why I am doing this is because I want to combine kernels with different variables so that I, for instance, can have the kernel expression SE_2 + SE_3, a squared exponential kernel on the second variable plus a squared exp. kernel on the third variable in the data set.

```
k_se_c <- function(x, y){
  res <- exp(-0.5*sum((x[c(2,10)] - y[c(2,10)])^2))+
    exp(-0.5*sum((x[c(3,10)] - y[c(3,10)])^2))
  return(res)
}
class(k_se_c) <- "kernel"

model_2 <- gausspr(Class ~ ., data = BreastCancer, kernel = k_se_c)
pre_gp <- predict(model_2, BreastCancer[,-10])
conf_2 <- confusionMatrix(pre_gp, BreastCancer$Class, positive = "malignant")
conf_2$byClass[1]
#Sensitivity 
#  0.2887029
```